# Find integers $s$ and $t$ such that $15s + 11t = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Could someone please explain this question to me? I know that such integers do NOT exist, but I could not prove it. "Either solve it or give a brief explanation as to why it is impossible." Thank you!

Find integers $s$ and $t$ such that $15s + 11t = 1$.

Comment: Actually, they exist. It is a well-known theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try $s=3$ and $t=-4$. (More generally, $s=3+11k$ and $t=-4-15k$ for any integer $k$ will work.)

You can know that such integers exist in advance from [Bezout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_identity), and find them using the Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm

$$3 \cdot 15 -4 \cdot 11 = 1$$

Answer (score 0):

$$15s+11t=1\iff11(s+t)+4s=1\iff4~\Big[3(s+t)+s\Big]-(s+t)=1=4-3.$$ Now let $s+t=3$ and $4s+3t=1$, which is a system of two equations in two unknowns, yielding $s=-8$ and $t=11$. Then it is trivial to show that all integers of the form $s+11n$ and $t-15n$ are also solutions to the initial equation.